# getChildView items onClickListener is effecting to all child items in ExapndabaleListView Android

Tags: java, android

Please look into this screen:

[image: please look into accept button image]

And when I click on accept changed to another button:

[image: i clicked on accept chnaged to another button image]

if I click on one `getChildView` List item in expandable list-view,it is also effecting to other child item while scrolling the screen. Here I changed button text when I click the `getChildview` item

Here I am clicking on accept button of one child ,then it should change to another button but while scrolling all child items buttons also changing

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private final Context context;

        private final List<String> headings;

        private List<DriverOrders> order;

        GroupHolder holder;

        public ExpandableListAdapter(final FragmentActivity fragmentActivity,
                                      final List<String> lidtDataHeaders, final List<DriverOrders> orders
        ) {
            this.context = fragmentActivity;
            this.headings = lidtDataHeaders;
            this.order = orders;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition) {

            return this.headings.get(childPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition) {

            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(final int groupPosition,
                                 final int childPosition, final boolean isLastChild,
                                 View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

            final String childName = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);



            // GroupHolder holder;
            holder = null;

            if (convertView == null) {
                final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.driver_child_layout, null);
                holder = new GroupHolder();

                holder.orderNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.orderNumber);
                holder.taskType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.taskType);
                holder.detaisl = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detaisl);
                holder.accept = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.accpet);
                holder.decline = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.decline);
                holder.started = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.started);
                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (GroupHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

           /* TextView orderNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.orderNumber);
            TextView taskType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.taskType);
            TextView detaisl = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detaisl);
            accept = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            decline = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.decline);

            started = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.started);*/

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("","inside convertview click"+parent.getChildAt(childPosition));
                }
            });


            holder.started.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (flag) {
                        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                        client.get(null, CommonUtility.SERVER_URI + "person-started/" + Long.parseLong(order.get(groupPosition).getOrderId().trim()), new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);

                                try {
                                    if (response.getString("STATUS").equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {

                                        mListener.onStarttrip(order.get(groupPosition).getOrderId(), order.get(groupPosition).getCustomerName(), order.get(groupPosition).getCustomerContact());
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);

                                if (statusCode == 404) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                                // When Http response code is '500'
                                else if (statusCode == 500) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                                // When Http response code other than 404, 500
                                else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }

                        });


                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Before started you have to accept the order", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }

            });

            holder.orderNumber.setText(order.get(groupPosition).getCustomerName());
            holder.taskType.setText(order.get(groupPosition).getCustomerContact());
            holder.detaisl.setText(order.get(groupPosition).getOrderId());

            holder.accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    Log.e("", "group positioins" + groupPosition);
                    String associateId = sessionManager.getUserDetails().get("associate_id");
                    String oredeerid = order.get(groupPosition).getOrderId();

                    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                    params.put("oid", oredeerid);
                    params.put("did", associateId);
                    requestForAcceptOrder(params, groupPosition);


                }

            });
            holder.decline.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    holder.decline.setFocusable(false);
                    holder.decline.setEnabled(false);
                    holder.decline.setClickable(false);
                    sessionManager.setDclineId(order.get(groupPosition).getOrderId());
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Order is declined", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DeclineReceiver.class);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, myIntent, 0);
                    Long timeInMillis = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis() + 1000;
                    Log.d("pass", "!!!!!!!");
                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, timeInMillis, 5400000, pendingIntent);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(final int groupPosition) {

            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(final int groupPosition) {

            return this.headings.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {

            return this.headings.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(final int groupPosition) {

            return groupPosition;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition,
                                 final boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                                 final ViewGroup parent) {
            final String headerTitle = (String) this.getGroup(groupPosition);
           /* final ExpandableListView mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) parent;
           mExpandableListView.expandGroup(0);*/

            // to display indicator of Expandable view from left to right
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {

                CabOrderFragment.this.expnListView
                        .setIndicatorBounds(
                                CabOrderFragment.this.expnListView
                                        .getWidth() - 50,
                                CabOrderFragment.this.expnListView
                                        .getWidth());
            } else {
                CabOrderFragment.this.expnListView
                        .setIndicatorBoundsRelative(
                                CabOrderFragment.this.expnListView
                                        .getWidth() - 50,
                                CabOrderFragment.this.expnListView
                                        .getWidth());

            }
            final LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.expandlistview_heading_group, null);
            // final ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView
            // .findViewById(R.id.ivHeadeImage);
            final TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvListHeader);
            // image.setImageResource(this.images[groupPosition]);

            lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()));
            lblListHeader.setTextSize(10);

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(final int groupPosition,
                                         final int childPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }


        private void requestForAcceptOrder(RequestParams params, final int groupPosition) {
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            client.get(null, CommonUtility.SERVER_URI + "accept", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {


                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject obj) {
                    try {
                        if (obj.getInt("code") == 0) {

                            holder.accept.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.decline.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            holder.started.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Oeder is  Placed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DriverOrdersReceiver.class);
                            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, myIntent, 0);
                            Log.d("stop alarm", "!!!!!!!");
                            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                            flag = true;

                            Log.e("", "object data" + obj.toString());

                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Oeder is Not Placed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                    super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);

                    if (statusCode == 404) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    // When Http response code is '500'
                    else if (statusCode == 500) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    // When Http response code other than 404, 500
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }


            });


        }

        /*private view holder class*/
        private class GroupHolder {
            TextView orderNumber;
            TextView taskType;
            TextView detaisl;
            Button accept;
            Button decline;
            Button started;

        }


    }
```

Comment: please anyone respond to this question

Comment: Are you updating your modal class "order" when it clicked ?@RameshReddy

Comment: No I am not updating order model.My problem is scrolling recyler view problem.When i click one list item its effecting other items when  i scroll view  @Ronak Joshi

Comment: I am also stuck on this problem :/

Comment: Please follow below answer if anyone have this type of problem...Its really working fine

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to [Recycling mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14108676/4224337), you need to **reset** the text color in `getChildView()` method.

This can be done by an `if{}else{}` case.

eg:

```
if(yourTextMustTakeTheDefaultColor){
   // set the default color in your text
} else {
   // set the other color
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

1) First don't use the holder as class variable.

Remove the class variable `GroupHolder holder;` from your adapter.

And change your `getChildView()` code like that:

```
GroupHolder holder;
if (convertView == null) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.driver_child_layout, null);
    holder = new GroupHolder();
    //the rest of code...
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (GroupHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
//the rest of code...
```

2) Like i've already told you to do: add `if else` case in `getChildView()` to update your view (i think you want to update accept/declined/started visibility) depending on child data.

eg:

```
if(order.get(groupPosition).isAcceptedVisible()){
   holder.accept.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
   holder.accept.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

3) Change your `requestForAcceptOrder()` to pass the also the child position.

```
private void requestForAcceptOrder(RequestParams params, final int groupPosition, final int childPosition)
```

4) In `onSuccess()` method you have the `groupPosition` and `childPosition`, update your List's data/model and call `notifyDataSetChanged();`, the system will take care of updating your views.

Comment: why text color has to do anything in this? i am also busting my head on this problem as i am stuck on this too, but your solution has nothing to do with this problem, read once more dude... 
Thing is that if we do make any changes in one child_view then during scrolling or even not scrolling(in my case) it updates other child_views simultaneously.. now problem should be clear.! :/ help if u know...!

Comment: Okay but how can i  use if and else conditions here.my button is accept button in above code .For example i am clicking on gropuposition 1 and in that am clicking on child item button (accept) ,then am changing button there,this whole logic is in accept.setOnClickListener() method.Please look into above code accept onClick Listener

Comment: yeah correct @M Faisal Hyder...My problem is same as yours...it updating to other child items even in case of not scrolling the view

Comment: @MFaisalHyder in the OP he said *"Here I am clicking on accept button of one child ,then it should change to another button but **while scrolling** all child items buttons also changing"* and i'am talking about text color because he mentioned this on [his duplicated question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628104/button-with-onclick-listeners-in-expandable-lisitview-affects-getchildview-metho)

Comment: @RameshReddy what "requestForAcceptOrder()" method do?

Comment: the "requestForAcceptOrder()"  method will get the data from server and in that method i have written code for changing text on button ,from "accpet" to "started" But this is effecting all accept buttons in other child items

Comment: @RameshReddy can you please post the code of this method?

Comment: @Rami i have posted the "requestForAcceptOrder()" method ,please look into that in above code

Comment: @RameshReddy you're using *holder* object in onSuccess() method, but in your code don't see from where you get this *holder*??

Comment: @Rami ,can i post that holder class ?

Comment: @RameshReddy I know you have a holder class, i'am talking about the holder object/instance... You should update the child view/holder not the the holder class.

Comment: @Rami  Now i posted full code for ExpandableListviewAdapter ,please look into that .Suggest me how to update holder insatnce in that

Comment: Thanks @Rami But what  isAcceptedVisible() method contains and if i dont decalre Holder as field variable ,how can i access holder instance inside OnClickListeners of accept button...Please suggest me here

Comment: @RameshReddy isAcceptedVisible() (or name it as you want) is a method in your Model class that will return boolean value to know if Child should hide or not the accepted button. Don't update the holder inside you ClickListeners, you should update your data list (the child model), then call *notifyDataSetChanged()* to refresh the views. Maybe you also need to add isDeclined() and isStarted() methods in your model to save declined and started state.

Comment: I think this is the last comment  for this Question.Thanks @Rami..Its Wworking fine now..Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the problem is that you aren't using the view in your onclick method to make the changes required in your UI. So the problem is context here. Holder object is created and destroyed for each group and you should use v from public void onClick(View v) to make any changes to the UI always, be it for the click on the group header of child views.

PS. I would suggest to have the Async task change data in a Model and just call notifydatasetchanged() on the adapter on returning a success.

Cheers